# [Redmi 1S][GPS] Unable to finding location using GPS

Tags: gps, location-services

When I search or ask application to find my location using GPS or Network location service (such as Path, GMaps, etc) this will let looping continuously "trying to retrieve your current location".

Any one find this issue also?